# jQuery UI Datepicker.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker. How can I add a class to the  element on click event.

Below is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function(){

   $('#calendar').datepicker();
   $('#calendar').children('td').click(function(){
         $(this).addClass('selected');
   });

});
```

Comment: Do you really need to set the class *selected*? You could inherit and set your style on the class *ui-datepicker-current-day* instead.

Comment: try this $('#calendar').children('td').addClass('selected');

Comment: @anujarora That would add the class to *all* `<td>` elements (if it worked), I'm guessing the OP wants it only on the selected date.

Comment: Actually, I need to add several classes depending on situation. Therefore, this method does not suit my case.

Comment: Okay, but then I guess you also need to remove the class when a new date is selected?

Comment: Are you looking to let the user click/select more than one date?

Comment: Yes, I neen to remove this class if user select new date, and to transfer this class to this new date.

Comment: Wouldn't modifying the jQuery UI CSS do the trick? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wBqVj/

Comment: And yes, I need to let user select more than one date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that should get you started, anyway:

```
var selectedDay = new Date().getDate();

$(function() {
    $("#calendar").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            // Save the selected day on select (if you show other months dates, you should save the selected month also.)
            selectedDay = inst.selectedDay;
        },
        // This is run for every day visible in the datepicker.
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            if (date.getDate() == selectedDay) {
                return [true, "selected", ""]; // Here you set your css class
            } else {
                return [true, ""]
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

The `beforeShowDay` function will take care of setting the css class and remove it from other days.

Of course you can extend this to work with multiple selected dates, this is just to show where you can start.